# How do you get Separate Color-schemes for Gvim and Vim?

Tags: vim

I have used vim for a while now, but after my friend introduced me to gvim, I'm trying to use it now. I have basic vimrc settings of :

```
set guifont=Monaco:h17
colorscheme zellner
set number
syntax on
```

I noticed that the settings were applied to my gvim. I want a different colorscheme for gvim and vim as I usually open the files I'll read quickly with vim or vi, and use gvim as my main code editor.

I heard people talk about the .gvimrc file, but I don't have it where my .bashrc, .zshrc, and .vimrc are.

How do I have separate colorschemes for gvim and vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim doesn't create either `~/.vimrc` or `~/.gvimrc` for you so you have to create them on your own.

You can either create the missing file in your shell, then edit in Vim:

```
$ touch ~/.gvimrc
$ vim ~/.gvimrc
<some editing>
:wq
```

or do everything from Vim:

```
:e ~/.gvimrc
<some editing>
:wq
```

Note: `~/.vimrc` is still sourced whether you have a `~/.gvimrc` or not so your `gvimrc` can be kept lightweight by only having GUI-specific options and overrides. In your case:

```
" ~/.vimrc
colorscheme zellner
set number
syntax on

" ~/.gvimrc
set guifont=Monaco:h17
colorscheme slate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a single `~/.vimrc`:

```
if has("gui_running")
    colorscheme zellner
else
    colorscheme blue
endif
```

See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#has() and http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#feature-list